# Allow Access to Apache 2 Server on local network

Tags: networking, server, apache2, localhost

04.3 LTS.

I want to allow access to other devices to my localhost.
My IP is 192.168.1.249 and the apache server is working for those addresses:

```
localhost/myapp
esolutions/myapp
192.168.1.249/myapp
```

Here is My default config:
/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName esolutions

    ServerAdmin iheb@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    <Directory /var/www/html>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    Order deny,allow
    AllowOverride All
    allow from all
    Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    allow from all
    Order deny,allow
    Require all granted
    </Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

and my hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       najda-PowerEdge-R430

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

192.168.1.249         esolutions
```

Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Solution is to allow traffic on port 80:

```
sudo ufw allow 'Apache'
```

You can verify the change by typing:

```
sudo ufw status
```

Comment: what i can do for port 3000 or 8000

Comment: got it 
`sudo ufw allow 3000/tcp`
by the way thanks